# Firebase write query is lagging animation

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I make the following firebase query but for some reason it lags my app.

```
const prefRef = firebase.firestore().collection('lobby').doc(lobbyNumber).collection('person').doc(docId)

prefRef.update({
            [restid]: sentiment
 })
```

Is there a way to make a write firebase query in the background without severely lagging the app?

Comment: Please edit the question to illustrate how you have identified this code as "lagging the app" and what you're doing to measure that.  The the update is expected to take some time and will be asynchronous. The required internet access is not immediate.

Comment: Hi @Preston, could you elaborate on how this code snippet is slowing your application?